# How to add a redirection in Nuxt router middleware?

Tags: nuxt.js, middleware

I have created a middleware to check if new user email has been verified `middleware/verify_email.js`:

```
export default function (context) {
  if (context.$auth.loggedIn && !context.$auth.user.email_verified_at) {
    console.log('logged in with email not verified');
    return context.redirect('/auth/verify');
  }
}
```

Then, I have set this middlware globally in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
  router: {
    middleware: ['auth', 'verify_email']
  },
```

But it seems I'm getting an infinite loop, the page in not not responding. It responds again as soon as I comment the redirect line.

> NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/auth/verify".

I probably need to add an exception to this middleware for the page `auth/verify` but I can't figure out how.

Any idea how I should fix this issue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I already did a similar auth middleware in Nuxt.js

You have to skip the middleware if you are on the `'/auth/verify'` route, as follows:

```js
export default function (context) {

  if (context.route.name === "auth-verify")
    // skip middleware
    return
  }

  if (context.$auth.loggedIn && !context.$auth.user.email_verified_at) {
    console.log('logged in with email not verified');
    return context.redirect('/auth/verify');
  }
}
```